# MySQL db join query

Tags: mysql

I am working with an Employee database in Mysql. My Db contains the following tables

```
    mysql> describe edept;     
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+  
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |  
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| dept  | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+


mysql>describe esal;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| basic | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| pf    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> describe edesig;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| desig | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+


mysql> select * from edetails inner join edept on edetails.dept=edept.id;
+----+--------+-----+------+-------+-------+----+----+------------------+
| id | name   | age | dept | desig | basic | pf | id | dept             |
+----+--------+-----+------+-------+-------+----+----+------------------+
|  1 | swetha |  21 |    3 |     2 |     2 |  2 |  3 | Business Process |
+----+--------+-----+------+-------+-------+----+----+------------------+


mysql> describe edetails;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name  | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| age   | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| dept  | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| desig | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| basic | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| pf    | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I have to get values for ***dept,desig,basic,pf*** from the tables  edept.dept,edesig.desig,esal.basic,esal.pf respectively.
   I used foreign keys for all the   fields for which i have to retrieve values from other tables.And i tried a sample inner join query. but i got the output as follows:

```
 mysql> select * from edetails inner join edept on edetails.dept=edept.id;
    +----+--------+-----+------+-------+-------+----+----+------------------+
    | id | name   | age | dept | desig | basic | pf | id | dept             |
    +----+--------+-----+------+-------+-------+----+----+------------------+
    |  1 | swetha |  21 |    3 |     2 |     2 |  2 |  3 | Business Process |
    +----+--------+-----+------+-------+-------+----+----+------------------+

My edept table contains the following:


 mysql> select * from edept;
+----+------------------+
| id | dept             |
+----+------------------+
|  3 | Business Process |
+----+------------------+



How can i eliminate duplicate columns. i need the value "business process" in the dept field of the edept table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this::

```
    select 
    edetails.id,
    edetails.name,
    edetails.age,
    edetails.dept, 
    edesig.desig,
    edetails.basic,
    edetails.pf,
    edept.dept

     from edetails 
        inner join edept on edetails.dept=edept.id
INNER JOIN edesig on edesig.id=edetails.desig
```

Comment: mysql> select * from edetails inner join edept on edetails.dept=edept.id group by dept throws an error            ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'dept' in group statement is ambiguous

Comment: No Shashi i still get the same output

Comment: @Swetha:SHow me the out put you are getting...
It will be easier for me then

Comment: @Swetha: Show us the create table of `edebt` too

Comment: The output is same as what i mentioned in my question.

Comment: my requirement is in the dept column of the edetails i wana fill the value of edept.dept.

Comment: @Swetha: Have added the `desig` column, do you also need the join with the esal?

Comment: @Swetha: Its my pleasure and thanks for asking so patiently :-P